# Angular cli: Module not found: cant resolve x

Tags: angular

I am trying to use medium-editor in my angular project. The directory is using the following import:

```
import { isPropertyUpdated } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/shared';
```

Although the path is correct and the import is allegedly successful, I keep getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'@angular/forms/src/directives/shared' in 
'myproject/src/app'
```

Why cli doesn't find this directory?

Comment: Are you sure that you can import that? Normally you should only import elements from tne modules entry point, in this case @angular/forms. If the element isnt available there, then is most likely some implementation details. This means that it isnt part of the public API and it should be used/imported

Comment: You can use the editor like this with angular, https://stackblitz.com/edit/medium-editor-angular7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html